# com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0 leads to error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my project I was using the following version of GCM library.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
```

Now I update it in to the following version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
02-05 23:51:29.205 18410-18410/com.example.app E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
02-05 23:51:29.205 18410-18410/com.example.app E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
02-05 23:51:29.238 18410-18452/com.example.app E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

I have configured my project with the following too

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

.

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of GoogleServices require a JSON file that contains configuration information about your app and account.

Follow the [instructions provided here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config).

You might also see better results by upgrading to the latest build tools (as of 5 Feb 2016):

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

and

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta2'
```

The new tools expect the google-services plugin to be applied at the **bottom** of the build file, as shown in [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/build.gradle).  FWIW, I'm building with these settings and not seeing the error.

Additional information about the `google-services.json` file, with troubleshooting tips, is [provided here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).

Comment: Ya. Sure. I have already configured and past that google-services.json into my project in previous version play-services-gcm:7.8.0. And i tried by changing it again. But the same error is seen.

Comment: Is beta is prefix adding to the trial version? Then is it good using beta version forever?

Comment: @VinilChandran: I'm not sure what you are asking.  The tools seem to be evolving and improving all the time.  I try to stay close to the latest released versions.  Release notes are [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-studio-20-beta.html).

Comment: @qbix Thanks for your help. I have solved the issue with your help. And I also changed the graddle inside C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\   from gradle-2.8  to gradle-2.10.